# Disable lightweight solution load prompt

Tags: visual-studio-2017

In VS2017 lightweight solution load is disabled by default and since I don't want it I am happy. BUT there is an annoying prompt which prompts me to enable it when I load a solution with a "Large" number of projects.

Is it possible to disable this prompt, so I do not enable it by accident ?

I have searched Tools -> options and the registry to no avail. Also what is a "large" number of projects I have not been able to find the number. Perhaps if one could raise the number to say 100000 then the prompt would never appear.

Comment: Cyrille kindly offered a solution for a single VS Solution, which could have worked, but unfortunately it does not. I would very much prefer a machine wide setting to disable the prompt for all solutions. But even disabling it for a single solution would be great.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Lightweight Solution prompt is shown three times, per solution, then a setting is stored locally which prevents it being shown again.

From: [developercommunity.visualstudio.com](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/26316/lightweight-solution-tip-to-enable-try-it.html): Viktor Veis: 27 Mar 2017:

> The lightweight solution message is
>   shown 3 times per solution. These settings are stored in the `suo` file,
>   so deleting the file or the `.vs` folder next to solution will trigger
>   another 3 messages.
>
> We're working on improving this experience in a future release.

Beetlejuice! Beetlejuice! Beetlejuice! *Sigh*

Comment: Thank you. You are correct I just tested it. That is comforting at least. But MS should have provided a way to disable the prompt for good. It is dangerous if you accidentaly enables this and suddenly your plugins (like Resharper) no longer works. Probably easy to disable again, but you will probably waste minutes or even hours because you have forgotten why.

Comment: The info is in the .suo file which is in some binary format so not easy to hack either I guess

Comment: Dude, you've saved me half a day of hell.
The Tools/Options/Project&Solutions setting had no effect. Nor the right-click solution explorer setting (cool that it's there, not cool it has no effect)
Manually deleting .vs dir sorted this and changed BUILD times from >5 mins to 20s. 
Microsoft. Sort the tooling, please.

Answer (score 4):

This message do not show again after setting the Lightweight solution load  to disabled instead of default.

To do this, select your solution and in the property window (default F4) set the Lightweight load to Disabled

Screenshots here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/optimize-visual-studio-startup-time#speed-up-solution-load

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately your solution does not work. After pressing F4 and choosing Disabled, I closed the Solution and opened it again. I still get the prompt even though the setting is "Disabled". I would also guess as much because  "Default" is "Disabled"

Comment: BTW. Perhaps you misread the question. It is not Lightweight load I want disabled (it already is). It is the annoying prompt that asks me to enable lightweight load I want to avoid